# Printing rows with certain text in column 2 with app script

Tags: google-apps-script, printing

I need to print off certain rows in a google sheet depending on what is in column 2 of that row. I know how to find the rows with a for loop but the rest eludes me. Perhaps my googling skills are rusty.

This is what I have.

```
var app = SpreadsheetApp;
var rows = app.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet").getMaxRows().toString();
var rows = rows.replace(".0","");

function findRows(){
for (var counter = 1; counter <= rows; counter = counter+1){
  if(app.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet").getRange(counter, 2) == "example" || "example2"){
     
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Find the correct rows

```
function findrows() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const osh = sh.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const vs = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  let s = vs.map(r => {
    if(r[1] == "Example" || r[1] == "example2") {
      return r;
    }
  }).filter(e => e);
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(s));
  //you can output to a sheet with something like
  //sheet.getRange(1,1,s.length,s[0].length).setValues(s);
  osh.getRange(1,1,s.length,s[0].length).setValues(s);//put on another sheet
}

Execution log
4:56:34 PM  Notice  Execution started
4:56:35 PM  Info    [[2,"Example",4,5],[5,"Example",7,8],[9,"Example",11,12],[12,"Example",14,15]]
4:56:35 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Data:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 2 | Example | 4 | 5 |
| 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
| 5 | Example | 7 | 8 |
| 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
| 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 |
| 9 | Example | 11 | 12 |
| 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 |
| 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 |
| 12 | Example | 14 | 15 |
| 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 |

BTW Printing is not easily done from Javascript or Google Apps Script

Comment: That is much better than what I had. What if I create a new sheet, add info from code above, print (there is code on another question that shows how to print a range), than delete the sheet?